# Xamarin iOS Storyboard, child view half width then parent. view

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uistoryboard

I am new to iOS UI development. and i am stuck in the below issue.

I am trying to give half of the width of parent view to 2 child views. (See image). I can't set multiplier to less than zero. Both red and green child view should be equal in width, and width should be half of the parent view.

I am using visual studio for development.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the Multiplier to `1:2` as it works with ratios.

I feel this is a bug in the iOS designer in Visual Studio as the Multiplier is a floating point number. from the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1):

> Multiplier: The value of attribute 2 is multiplied by this floating point number. In this case, the multiplier is 1.0.

In Xamarin Studio, iOS Designer a ratio is accepted, Also `1/2` `0.5`:

[image]

And In Xcode:

[image]

It even gets added to the source of the xib/storyboard like so:

```
<constraint id="9" firstItem="3" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="1:2"/>
```

so as a work around you could edit the .xib or .storyboard file, but thats not ideal.

An alternative to setting the multiplier you could set:

**RedView**

- LeadingSpace to superview.leadingspace
- TrailingSpace to superview.CenterX

**GreenView**

- LeadingSpace to superview.CenterX
- TrailingSpace to superview.trailingspace

This will do the same as setting the width to half the the width size of the superview.

TBH Visual studio's and Xamarin studio's iOS Designers are not very good in comparision to Xcode for adding complicated constraints (this is not that complicated but it still fails). I would suggest trying to edit it in Xcode, if you can.

**Update**

If you want to add them programatically, add this in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    greenView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    redView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    View.AddConstraints(new NSLayoutConstraint[]{
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create(redView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create(redView, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create(redView, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0),

        NSLayoutConstraint.Create(greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create(greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1, 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint.Create(greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, redView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 0),
    });
}
```

It will make a view like so:

[image: port] [image: land]

Comment: multiplier not accepting it. only accepting integer value. can you please explain it a little bit.

Comment: thank you for great explanation. indeed it is bug in Visual studio iOS Designer. i still have 1 question. how can i set trailingSpace to superview.CenterX ? There is no option to edit constraints. Should i do it programmatically ?
BTW i have found another cheap solution.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the programmatic way, I also set the view to be in the center of the screen but you can change that to what suits your needs.

Comment: you could also have a look at this library https://github.com/FluentLayout/Cirrious.FluentLayout which helps simplify some of the autolayout settings in code

Comment: thank you for awesome answer and explanation. i have accepted the ans. Just wondering currently there is no way of achieving it in VS iOS Designer ?

Comment: The only way is to try and set the constraints that you set programmatically in the designer, I tried it in the Xamarin studio iOS designer but it was not setting the green view to leading = superview.centerX no idea why. So i would assume you might be able to but you'll need to fight with the VS Designer to get it to work.